# Building a photo array from database tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, foreach

So I have been fighting this for months now and am hoping to find a solution here once and for all. I am using [phppwinty](http://www.bradpineau.com/PHPPwinty/) as a php library for [pwinty.com](http://pwinty.com).

In the default example provided by the author, the images array is created like the example below with all the variables hard coded as an example.

```
$photo1 = $pwinty->addPhoto($order, "4x6", "http://www.picisto.com/photos/picisto-20120608100135-925870.jpg", "1", "ShrinkToFit");
$photo2 = $pwinty->addPhoto($order, "6x6", "http://www.picisto.com/photos/picisto-20120601010631-895061.jpg", "4", "ShrinkToFit");
$photo3 = $pwinty->addPhoto($order, "5x7", "http://www.picisto.com/photos/picisto-20120626210525-763773.jpg", "3", "ShrinkToFit");
```

*(note: in training, I have found out we don't necessarily need to add the integer after photo. instead of: `photo1` it can just be `photo`.)*

Now the $order variable is fine to stay. Next is the size, image source, and quantity. These are the only 3 variables I am worried about at the moment. With the shopping cart I have these unfortunately are broken up into 3 different tables.

```
-- order_options -- The table for the size variable
   --option_value -- The column for the size variable 
   --order_id -- Relationship column 

-- order_products -- The table for the product id's and qty in the order 
   -- product_id -- The column for the product id variable 
   -- product_quantity -- The column for the quantity variable
   -- order_id -- Relationship column 

-- products -- The table for the image source variable 
   -- product_image -- The column for the image source variable 
   -- product_id -- Relationship column
```

I get the order_id into the script with a get variable: `$order_id = $_GET['id'];`

I have attempted to `JOIN` all the tables together with relationships and have got nothing but errors, Though I don't beleive the problem is in the `JOIN` but the way I have the `foreach` set up.

My `JOIN` and `foreach` looks like this right now:

```
foreach ($db->query("SELECT orderproducts.product_id, orderoptions.option_value, products.product_image FROM order_products as orderproducts INNER JOIN order_options as    orderoptions ON orderproducts.order_id = orderoptions.order_id INNER JOIN products as products ON orderproducts.product_id = products.product_id WHERE              orderproducts.order_id = $order_id AND orderproducts.product_id = $product_id") as $row)
    $order_variables[] = $row;

if (count($order_variables) > 0): 
    foreach ($order_variables as $row):

        $product_id = $row['product_id'];

        $product_quantity = $row['product_quantity'];

        $size = $row['option_value'];

        $product_source = "https://www.alphahq.org/uploads/images/".$row['product_image']."";

        $photo = $pwinty->addPhoto($order, $size, $product_source, $product_quantity, "ShrinkToFit");

    endforeach;
endif;
```

The reason I say I believe the problem is in how the foreach is set up is because the 1 error I get in my browser when I run the script is as follows:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/www/alphahq.org/libraries/phppwinty/print.php on line 35
```

According to my code editor line 35 is the foreach statement from above.

```
    foreach ($db->query("SELECT orderproducts.product_id, orderoptions.option_value, products.product_image FROM order_products as orderproducts INNER JOIN order_options as    orderoptions ON orderproducts.order_id = orderoptions.order_id INNER JOIN products as products ON orderproducts.product_id = products.product_id WHERE              orderproducts.order_id = $order_id AND orderproducts.product_id = $product_id") as $row)
    $order_variables[] = $row;
```

I hope I have been descriptive enough to finally get a solution to this darn problem once in for all. Thank you for your help in advance and hope we can work out a solution together. Happy coding.

**If I can provide any more information that you believe would be helpful, please simply comment kindly below requesting the information.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$db->query()` will return a result set.  Unless you are doing something in the `query()` method, you are working with a resource, not an object or array.  `foreach` needs something it can iterate over.

Have you considered using:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT orderproducts.product_id, orderoptions.option_value, products.product_image FROM order_products as orderproducts INNER JOIN order_options as orderoptions ON orderproducts.order_id = orderoptions.order_id INNER JOIN products as products ON orderproducts.product_id = products.product_id WHERE orderproducts.order_id = $order_id AND orderproducts.product_id = $product_id");

$order_variables = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $order_variables[] = $row;
}
```

That should produce a multi-dimensional array with your DB rows in `$order_variables`.

*(Please note that I used the OOP version of MySQLi in my example, I am not sure if that is what you are using.  If not, modify as necessary.)*

**EDIT**

Looking at your query a little closer, I believe part of the problem is that your variable values are not surrounded in single quotes.  This may work better for you instead.  MySQL likes its values (especially non-numerical ones) in single quotes:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT orderproducts.product_id, orderoptions.option_value, products.product_image FROM order_products as orderproducts INNER JOIN order_options as orderoptions ON orderproducts.order_id = orderoptions.order_id INNER JOIN products as products ON orderproducts.product_id = products.product_id WHERE orderproducts.order_id = '$order_id' AND orderproducts.product_id = '$product_id'");
```

Comment: Thanks :-), I happened to see the question as it popped up.  Luck of the draw.

Comment: is the query trying to use `$product_id` just like my `$order_id`? The product id is not pre-populated like the order id is.

Comment: The reason I ask is because I am getting this error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in /home/www/alphahq.org/libraries/phppwinty/print.php on line 39`

Comment: According to your query and intended method of assignment, it looks like your `$product_id` variable is supposed to be coming from the `product_id` field in your `order_products` table

Comment: In that case it looks like you may have a problem with your query.  Can you run the query in an sql client or phpMyAdmin?

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column '$product_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43069/discussion-between-user2948950-and-crackertastic)

Comment: Forgive me, but I'm not in a position to join in chat.  However, I have updated my answer.  I overlooked that you do not have any single quotes around your variable values.

Comment: What I figured out with the old query: 
#1054 - Unknown column '$product_id' in 'where clause'
If I replace order_id with 20 (an order id) and product_id with 2 (a product id) the query runs. It returns nothing but it runs.
If I do 20 for order id and 24 with product id. (the product that was ordered with the order number) I get the product_id, option_value (size), and prodcut_image (image source)
So the problem is identifiying the product_id before hand.
This query also only returns one result. What happens if an order has two different images in it?